# Uncaught typeError:undefined is not a function while using slide left infullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js in my website. I want the horizontal slides to slide automatically. For that I am using following code. But I am getting error in console:

```
Uncaught typeError:undefined is not a function.
```

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            anchors: ['home', 'about', 'why-us','services','team','contact'],
            autoScrolling: true,
            css3: true,
            afterRender: function () {
                setInterval(function () {
                    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you have undefined fullpage method.

Comment: where you are getting error i mean on which line ?

Comment: Hi Kenny, I am getting error just above -  }, 3000);

Comment: Did you remember to load the fullpage.js library prior to this code? (e.g. `<script src='path/to/fullpage.js'></script>`)

Comment: Hi monkeysight. Sorry but I didnt get you!

Comment: Please help! Its not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not including the needed files correctly. 
Make sure they are in the location you are specifying.

As pointed in the docs and as you can see in [the examples provided](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/examples), this is the structure you have to follow to add the needed files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- This following line is needed in case of using the default easing option or when using another
 one rather than "linear" or "swing". You can also add the full jQuery UI instead of this file if you prefer -->
<script src="vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>


<!-- This following line needed in the case of using the plugin option `scrollOverflow:true` -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
```

Comment: NO. I changed the structure as you said. But nothing happened. I also tried to implement it in one of your examples.. but its not working. The problem is with this -  $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();

Comment: The problem is solved. I copied the code from the your fiddle that was working. Thank you.

Comment: @SachinSangde you should accept the answer if it solved your problem so it can help other people in the future with your same problem.

Comment: @SachinSangde but this was the reason for sure. You were including them bad.